# why order by desc and limit query is taking too much time?

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization, postgresql-10

Currently, i was trying to make a sql query on my postgresql table, all things was going good unless i sort my query by Price in DESC, after this filter query is taking almost round about 60 sec to return results. before that, if i am sorting it in ASC, it takes on few mseconds.
Here it is my query and its query plan.

```
explain analyze 
select * 
from products_allproducts 
Where lower("SNR_Category")=lower('Mobile Apps') 
ORDER BY "SNR_Price" ASC 
LIMIT 36 OFFSET 0;
```

and its query plan is

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.44..19620.51 rows=36 width=595) (actual time=221.081..221.148 rows=36 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using snr_price_desc on products_allproducts  (cost=0.44..58484176.24 rows=107310 width=595) (actual time=221.079..221.145 rows=36 loops=1)
         Filter: (lower(("SNR_Category")::text) = 'mobile apps'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 83205
 Planning time: 0.101 ms
 Execution time: 221.167 ms
(6 rows)
```

but as soon as, i sort it in DESC, it takes almost 60 seconds. like this.

```
explain analyze
select * from products_allproducts 
Where lower("SNR_Category")=lower('Mobile Apps') 
ORDER BY "SNR_Price" desc 
LIMIT 36 OFFSET 0;
```

and its query plan is.

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.44..19620.51 rows=36 width=595) (actual time=10000.687..28416.939 rows=36 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using snr_price_desc on products_allproducts  (cost=0.44..58484176.24 rows=107310 width=595) (actual time=10000.686..28416.932 rows=36 loops=1)
         Filter: (lower(("SNR_Category")::text) = 'mobile apps'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 7679720
 Planning time: 0.085 ms
 Execution time: 28416.960 ms
(6 rows)
```

I have find the problem, if i remove limit section from desc query its taking only few mili seconds

Can anyonle tell me that how can i improve my speed while sorting in desc with limit query? because at end i need only few records.

here is query of DESC which taking few seconds.

```
explain analyze 
select * from products_allproducts 
Where "SNR_Category"~*'Mobile Apps' 
ORDER BY "SNR_Price" desc;
```

and its query plan.

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather Merge  (cost=128208.97..131324.65 rows=26704 width=595) (actual time=142.024..156.919 rows=32008 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Sort  (cost=127208.95..127242.33 rows=13352 width=595) (actual time=136.088..138.304 rows=10669 loops=3)
         Sort Key: "SNR_Price" DESC
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 5336kB
         ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on products_allproducts  (cost=4796.35..122731.02 rows=13352 width=595) (actual time=73.671..116.140 rows=10669 loops=3)
               Recheck Cond: (("SNR_Category")::text ~* 'Mobile Apps'::text)
               Heap Blocks: exact=5113
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on snr_category_trigram_idx  (cost=0.00..4788.34 rows=32045 width=0) (actual time=74.976..74.976 rows=32008 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (("SNR_Category")::text ~* 'Mobile Apps'::text)
 Planning time: 0.293 ms
 Execution time: 163.839 ms
(13 rows)
```

Comment: Please post the plans as text, not images. Also add the version of Postgres.

Comment: PostgreSQL version is 10

Comment: `Execution time: 163.839 ms` - the last statement does not take "a few seconds" it only takes 0.163 seconds. And the second one doesn't take 60 seconds - only 28

Comment: yes last statement is taking 0.163 because i did not use limit, in second last i use limit and it takes 28 seconds and sometimes it takes 60sec.

Comment: The last one is also different than the others because it uses:  "SNR_Category"~*'Mobile Apps'   whereas the others use: `lower("SNR_Category")=lower('Mobile Apps')`. What if you use `~*` in the "slow" one as well?

Comment: its not depending upon ~* or lower("SNR_Category"). its taking long time due to limit query.

Comment: Duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185819/postgresql-limit-1-much-slower-than-fetching-all-rows ? (plus dozens of others)